# Remove class when at top of page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to remove a class from my sticky nav using jQuery. The class was added after scrolling down the page and reaching certain sections ( tags).

Currently, the behavior acts as expected for the code I wrote. The CSS is applied after the user scrolls the specific sections with the corresponding IDs. However, when the user scrolls all the way back to the top, the CSS remains applied to the nav. I am looking to remove this class when the user is not viewing one of the sections in the nav.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
// ADDS ACTIVE CLASS TO LINKS IN NAV ON SCROLL

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.navLink').each(function(event) {
      if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 40) {
        $('.navLink').not(this).removeClass('navLinkActive');
        $(this).addClass('navLinkActive');
      }
    });
  });
});

// SMOOTH SCROLLING

jQuery($ => {
  // The speed of the scroll in milliseconds
  const speed = 1000;

  $('a[href*="#"]')
    .filter((i, a) => a.getAttribute('href').startsWith('#') || a.href.startsWith(`${location.href}#`))
    .unbind('click.smoothScroll')
    .bind('click.smoothScroll', event => {
      const targetId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href').split('#')[1];
      const targetElement = document.getElementById(targetId);

      if (targetElement) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(targetElement).offset().top
        }, speed);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 300vh;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navLink {
  color: #000;
 }

.navLinkActive {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.section {
  height: 50vh;
}

#nonNavSection {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="headerNav" class="sticky">
  <a class="navLink" href="#foo">Foo</a>
  <a class="navLink" href="#bar">Bar</a>
  <a class="navLink" href="#baz">Baz</a>
</nav>

<div id="nonNavSection" class="section"><p>Content unrelated to sections below.</p></div>
<div id="foo" class="section"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
<div id="bar" class="section"><p>Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam.</p></div>
<div id="baz" class="section"><p>Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl.</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you just need an `else` clause in your scroll handler, probably something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.navLink').each(function(event) {
      if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 40) {
        $('.navLink').not(this).removeClass('navLinkActive');
        $(this).addClass('navLinkActive');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('navLinkActive');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the removal of the active class from the `this` in block `else { ... }`. Like this:

```
else {
    $(this).removeClass("navLinkActive");
}
```

```js
// ADDS ACTIVE CLASS TO LINKS IN NAV ON SCROLL

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        $(".navLink").each(function (event) {
            if (y >= $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top - 40) {
                $(".navLink").not(this).removeClass("navLinkActive");
                $(this).addClass("navLinkActive");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("navLinkActive");
            }
        });
    });
});

// SMOOTH SCROLLING

jQuery(($) => {
    // The speed of the scroll in milliseconds
    const speed = 1000;

    $('a[href*="#"]')
        .filter((i, a) => a.getAttribute("href").startsWith("#") || a.href.startsWith(`${location.href}#`))
        .unbind("click.smoothScroll")
        .bind("click.smoothScroll", (event) => {
            const targetId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href").split("#")[1];
            const targetElement = document.getElementById(targetId);

            if (targetElement) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("html, body").animate(
                    {
                        scrollTop: $(targetElement).offset().top,
                    },
                    speed
                );
            }
        });
});
```

```css
body {
    min-height: 300vh;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.navLink {
    color: #000;
}

.navLinkActive {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.section {
    height: 50vh;
}

#nonNavSection {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="headerNav" class="sticky">
    <a class="navLink" href="#foo">Foo</a>
    <a class="navLink" href="#bar">Bar</a>
    <a class="navLink" href="#baz">Baz</a>
</nav>

<div id="nonNavSection" class="section"><p>Content unrelated to sections below.</p></div>
<div id="foo" class="section"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
<div id="bar" class="section"><p>Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam.</p></div>
<div id="baz" class="section"><p>Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl.</p></div>
```

Comment: @John Wu Oh my, I can't believe I had the incorrect syntax when I tried that earlier. Thank you so much!